# How to change position of attribute added on Product description page?

Tags: magento2

I made an attribute of **text area** type and  when I upload an image using it, image appear in product tabs like this in **More information**. 
But I want it to appear before tabs. I added these lines in **catalog_product_view.xml** file.

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/topattributes.phtml" name="product.info.topattribute" after="-"/>      
</referenceContainer>
```

[image: its appearing in tab]

Comment: could elaborate little more , where you want to display it

Comment: before these tabs . this div of tabs. @ManojDeswal

Comment: above the tabs , these tabs will come below this image ?

Comment: Yes these tabs will come below @ManojDeswal

Comment: your tabs must be inside "product-lower-primary-column" right ?

Comment: I got the idea , I just need to know their containers ...so can place them at required place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66865/discussion-between-manoj-deswal-and-learner).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/topattributes.phtml" name="product.info.topattribute" before="product.info.details"  after="product.info.media" /> 
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: its coming now after breadcrumb

Comment: check my updated answer